# Adding Extra fields on Joomla Registration Form

Tags: joomla

How to add extra fields in Joomla2.5 registration form? I am using profile plugin but i also want to change the order of the fields. Any Suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Copy the profile plugin and change it to do what you want, then install it and unpublish the old one.

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional fields to the registration form by changing the database and a core component file.

First of all take a look of components\com_users\models\forms directory and there is a XML file called registration.xml. This is the file joomla creates the registration form fields. I hope you can understand this file and add what ever the necessary fields you want.

And after that check out your data base table called #__users and add the extra fields you want. (ex: if you want to add Telephone number add filed calld tp_no). And make sure to use the same name that you use in XML file "field name" for the database table column as well.

Comment: I already know that way but i am searching any plugin without changing core files.

Comment: @LalitJain When you start altering in the manor you are planning, typically you have to alter code. It is not that big a deal if you duplicate code format from another column/field. Also, use version control like GIT so you keep track if updates override your changes.

Comment: No this is not a way we do not want to alter core files.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you are looking for something like this?

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/authentication/14303

Probably the safest solution in the short and long term. I've not used it but it looks like it does what you want and from an interface rather than changing hard code.

Answer (score 0):

There is manual how do it. Turn on subtitles visit http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a6xsKLiXF40